# Social Sharing From Public Device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

We are developing a photo-booth style app in Unity.

The app will be deployed on an Android device and placed into a public space like a shopping mall.

We would like to allow users to share their images on social media. Facebook / Instagram.

Having checked how the native share functionality works - it uses the account logged into the device to share. However, we would like the users to be able to share to their own social media accounts.

Is this possible? It seems like the built in share functionality on Android would not allow for this.
Would we have to use API to achieve this kind of function?

We had the idea to present them with a form to log into their Facebook / Instagram account to share content.

Once its shared - it would need to logout and not keep the login details.

Does anyone know if there is perhaps an Asset for Unity to do such a thing?

Thanks!

Comment: [There's the Facebook SDK for Unity](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/examples/), which includes login functionality. I reckon you would want to ensure good security so onlookers can't glance the password when entered (i.e. a literal photo booth with curtain may be appropriate). Beyond that, you may want to do some user testing first to confirm that an appropriate percentage a) remembers their Facebook password while on the go, and b) is willing to enter it into an unknown third-party app (which to their knowledge, might do anything with their password, nevermind pricacy promises).

Comment: In case users by and large are unwilling to login, you could consider to either send them an email with the watermarked photo as attachment, or ask them to simply snap whatever you want them to snap with their phone (which then allows them to freely share it across all their preferred social networks), they after all already carry a camera with them. I've seen both approaches used in public booth apps.